# Replace string by calling a custom function to transform var into sub strings - Algo JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm, typescript

I'm trying to tansform a string to build it using variables and arguments.

```
The min length of __40 is 4. Max length is 16.
```

__40 is another string key, I need to extract the key from the string, convert it and replace it with the converted value (which will be the string referenced by the key), to do that I need to call a custom function [_getSentence()], it's possible to have several keys in the same sentence, I thought about make a regex but it looks complicated, isn't? Plus I don't know if I can call a customized function from a regex but I don't think so.

Maybe split the string to get all words (split by space), for each check if the word start by '__' and in this case  call my customized function, store the result and replace the current word by the string. But this new string could also contains another key that I need to convert.

What is the best algorithm to use here? DO you if there is a better solution? Mine should work.

I also have to deal with arguments that can be sent, but I don't have to manage args for sub-keys.

Here is the function, called by _getSentence() once the sentence has been converted, to replace args by values, but I thought also manage sub-keys here.

```
/**
 * Replace the tags in the text by the args.
 * @param message      The message.
 * @param args          The args to replace in the message.
 * @returns {string}    The string built.
 */
Lang.prototype._replaceArgsInText = function (message, args, lang) {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            message = message.replace((this.PATTERN_ARGS + i), args[i]);
        }

        // Check if some of the args was other language keys.
        return message;
    };
```

***Edit:*** 
**Final solution:**

```
/**
 * Replace the tags in the text by the args.
 * @param message      The message.
 * @param args          The args to replace in the message.
 * @returns {string}    The string built.
 * @private
 */
private _replaceArgsInText(message: any, args: any, lang: string): string{
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        message = message.replace((this.PATTERN_ARGS+i), args[i]);
    }

    // Check if some of the args was other language keys.
    message = this._replaceSubKeys(message, /__\w+/g, this._languages[lang][this._FIELD_CONTENT_LANG]);

    return message;
}

/**
 * Replace the sub keys into the sentence by the actual text.
 * @param sentence
 * @param rx
 * @param array
 * @returns {string|void}
 * @private
 */
private _replaceSubKeys(sentence, rx, array): string{

    return sentence.replace(rx, function(i) {
        var subSentence = array[i];
        // TODO Check if that's an object or a string.
        if(typeof subSentence == 'string'){
            return subSentence;
        }else{
            console.log('not a string!')
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What language are you asking about?  Your post is tagged `javascript`, but your sample code is not `javascript`.

Comment: Actually yes, it's typescrit, so it's like javascript but source code is object oriented.

Comment: I just changed the source code, sorry about that. It's true JS now.

Comment: This might be better here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your substitution parameters in a map with their name as keys, you can do something like this:

```
function replace(text, rx, map) {
  return text.replace(rx, function(k) { return map[k] });
}

var res = replace(
  "The min length of __40 is 4. Max length is 16.",
  /__\w+/g, // regex for the substitution format
  {__40: 'snake'}); // map of substitution parameters
```

The regex is `/__w+/g` to match the format of your parameters, and all parameters in the string. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q96P2/).

I'm also using the [`String.prototype.replace` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace) that also takes a function.